# How to label axis ticks in a scientific notation as in latex?

Tags: r

```
plot(1:10, (1:10)*1e6, xaxt='n', yaxt='n', xlab='', ylab='')
axis(2, (1:10)*1e6, (1:10)*1e6, las=2)
```

The axis ticks are shown as "1e+06", ...

How to show them like $1 \times 10^6$ (as in latex), ...?

Comment: Just some personal opinion: most readers of scientific papers are used to the e notation and it is in fact _scientific_ notation, I would not bother to change it from default. You might of course have other reasons!

Comment: FWIW, I absolutely hate the e annotation. :upsidedown:

Comment: You can use the `scales::label_math` function. https://scales.r-lib.org/reference/label_parse.html

Comment: Could you put a working example as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not super elegant, but this seems to work:

```r
plot(1:10, (1:10)*1e6, xaxt='n', yaxt='n', xlab='', ylab='')
labs <- sapply(sprintf("%d %%*%% 10^6", 1:10), \(x) parse(text = x))
axis(2, (1:10)*1e6, labs, las=2)
```

Comment: But you have to hard-code 10^6. How to let it automatically figure the best scientific notation?